# An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue after rails new in win10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

> An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.4), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4'
>   --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   bootsnap

I tried installing rails with railsinstaller & followed this, since I'm a newb to ruby and stuff.:

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-installation.htm

and after the 
`$ rails new app` command

I encounter that error I said above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because of some issues conflicting with rails and windows 10. So the immediate solution will be to downgrade bootsnap version in gemfile

```
gem 'bootsnap', '<= 1.1.0'
```

Another solution will be to follow rails installtion using https://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you already found the answer or not but the way I fixed it the issue was going into Gemfile, looking for bootsnap and manually changing it from I believe 1.1.0 to 1.4.4, save and run the bundle install command. You will most likely get a few other errors they are easily fixable the same way.  I am not sure why there are so many errors I suspect it has something to do with using an older version of rails.  I will update this section as I learn more.  I hope this helps or you already found a solution.